# Convert a multibyte UTF8 to wchar_t for usage with _wfopen()

Tags: c++, utf-8, wchar-t, wchar

There are different threads to similar problems, but after searching and trying a lot, I could not find a solution. So that's what I have:

There is a pathname of a file which originally has the name `"C:\F\鸡汤饭\abstr.txt"`. This is some internal representation where I do not have access to.

What I get in my application is this string converted to UTF-8 multi-byte handed over as a `char` array. So in this array I can find the data `"C:\F\é¸¡æ±¤é¥­\abstr.txt"`.

Now I want to open the related file. I found `_wfopen()` could do that job, but it expects a `wchar_t` string. So I tried to convert this multibyte UTF-8 `char` array to wchar_t via `mbstowcs()` - but this does not work, the resulting `wchar_t` array contains exactly the same data and `_wfopen()` fails.

So... any idea how I can open this file correctly?

Comment: I assume you have tried to use the standard `fopen` with your UTF-8 string and it didn't work?

Comment: Are you writing `C` or `C++`? Have you tried [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude correct. fopen() with Windows seems not to be able to deal with MB UTF8

Comment: What youu posted is the actual byte content of the file. Obviously to use it you'd need to convert it to a proper string. While C++ offers UTF8 types since C++11 (there are `char8_t`, `u8string` and `u16string` types) the stream operations are missing. The [codecvt_utf8_utf16](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) function that C++11 introduced for charset conversions was deprecated in C++ 17

Comment: @Elmi on the contrary, Windows works just fine with Unicode. The whole operating system is Unicode -UTF16 specifically. What you posted, is actually what a UTF8 string would look like if you treated individual bytes as characters. It's *C++* that doesn't handle UTF8 streams

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the path in an `std::filesystem::path`?  It offers member functions for returning the native path, for example.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @Elmi does your path actually have Chinese characters in it? This is a different matter then. Again, Windows (specifically, NTFS) allows Unicode in path names. To work with those paths though, you actually need to use Unicode strings and use the Unicode versions of the file functions.  You can use [filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) to produce a `u8strring` or `u16string`. The. link's example uses a UTF8 string literal : `fs::path p = fs::u8path(u8"要らない.txt");`, writes with `std::ofstream(p) ` then reads with `_wfopen(p.c_str(), L"r")`

Comment: @Elmi you also need to save your source code as a UTF8 or UTF16 file, otherwise the non-USASCII text may get mangled.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, the directory with that Chinese name 鸡汤饭 exists, so the given path is available. And it has nothing to do with my source file, the path is not hardcoded but handed over to my application as char-array (containing the mentioned multibyte UTF8). So the question is definitely: how can I convert a multibyte UTF8 to a wchar_t array which is accepted by _wfopen()

Comment: @Elmi I posted a link to just that. Use `filesystem::path` to make the conversion, use a UTF8 or UTF16 string literal to specify the path (if hard-coded). In some cases people are using `path` to convert arbitrary text between encodings precisely because `codecvt_utf8_utf16 ` is deprecated. Check [the filesystem::path docs and example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string).

Comment: PS: Every Windows user outside the US for the last 20+ years depends on its native Unicode support. Lawyers and accountants in Greece, Russia or China use local file names because nobody told them otherwise. C++ applications like Word, Excel that are compiled as Unicode have no problem working in any country. Problems occur only when people compile as ASCII then have to depend on the correct system locale for their applications to work properly. This isn't a Windows issue. Javascript, Java, C# all use Unicode natively and have no issues. Python 2 - a ton of SO questions about Unicode errors

Comment: If you are OK with hardcoding the filename, try `_wfopen(L"C:\\F\\鸡汤饭\\abstr.txt", L"r")`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution

```
fs::path p = fs::u8path(u8"要らない.txt");
```

using std::filesystem did work properly. Surprisingly this was introduced with C++17 but is already deprecated :-O